# findDeleted in mongoose-delete retrieves all elements with deleted field: true and false

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-deleteone

I use mongoose-delete library in my project. After soft delete, soft deleted data will be in recycle bin (I use findDeleted to get soft deleted data)

```
const Course = require("../models/Course");
const { mutipleMongooseToObject } = require("../../util/mongoose");
class MEcontrollers {
  me(req, res, next) {
    Course.find({}).then((course) => {
      res.render("me/me", { course: mutipleMongooseToObject(course) });
    });
  }
  bin(req, res, next) {
    Course.findDeleted()
      .then((course) => {
        console.log(mutipleMongooseToObject(course));
        res.render("me/bin", { course: mutipleMongooseToObject(course) });
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
}
module.exports = new MEcontrollers();
```

but it doesn't work, it takes all data in MongoDB, Please help me, thanks

Here is console.log with findDeleted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZZ3H.png)

Comment: There seems to be a bug. See https://github.com/dsanel/mongoose-delete/issues/136

Answer (score 0):

here is how I do it:

- when applying the plugin, don't use `overrideMethod: 'all'`, instead just override the methods you're using such as 'delete', 'restore',...
- use `Model.find({ deleted: true })` instead of `Model.findDeleted()`
- to find the not deleted ones just use `Model.find({ deleted: {$ne: true} })`